# Using C# LINQ to concat a filtered List<object> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

This is probably easy for someone more experienced with LINQ and the Lambda expressions in C#. I'm just starting out with them, so I must be missing something.

I have a custom object like this:

```
public class BusinessName {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have a list of these objects:

```
List<BusinessName> businessNames = new List<BusinessName>();
```

I want to convert this into a list of `string` with the `Name` property of the `BusinessName` object:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
```

Obviously, I could do this:

```
foreach (BusinessName name in businessNames) {
    names.Add(name.Name);
}
```

But, I want to try using the lambda expressions with LINQ so that I can put this into a one liner.

So, I tried:

```
names.AddRange(businessNames.Select(item => item.Name));
```

This works as expected, but is much slower than the foreach loop by 2x. I suspect this is because it's iterating the list twice, unlike the foreach loop.

So, I started looking for an alternative. I found `Concat()` but couldn't figure out how it was any different than `AddRange()`.

Does anyone know a way to do this in one pass with LINQ?

Comment: Can't really be done - unless you count ConvertAll as LINQ. However, I **severely** doubt this is a hotspot in your program.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @crush Try `names.AddRange(buisnessNames.ConvertAll(item => item.Name));`

Comment: I have, in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `names` is empty, what you're meant to do is this:

```
var names = businessNames.Select(item => item.Name).ToList();
```

Another option is to use the `List<T>`'s `ConvertAll` method, like so:

```
var names = buisnessNames.ConvertAll(item => item.Name);
```

However, if it may be not empty, you'd need to use an if statement too:

```
var names = new List<string>();
//some code
if (names.Any())
    names.AddRange(/*your selected method*/);
else
    names = //your selected method;
```

Comment: Lets say that names may or may not be empty, then what do you do?

Comment: @Peter Check using `Enumerable.Any`.

Comment: It won't be empty. I have a collection of `List<BusinessNames>` that I will be iterating over, and adding to the names List.

Comment: @crush Well there you go. It's all in here.

Comment: How is using `ConvertAll` any different than `Select`? They both reduce businessNames down to an Enumeration which equals 1 loop of the List. Now when it `AddRange` it will loop the list again to add each element.

Comment: Don't use `Enumerable.Any` if you're looking for performance.  Your initial thought is the best way to append using linq.  If you're looking for the most performant way, stick with your `foreach`.

Comment: @crush ConvertAll is better because it only does one iteration unless you need to add it to the list, which is not going to happen if you mentioned. **Either way**, the performance difference is so small it's effectively none.#

Comment: I ran a test, and `ConvertAll` is only slightly slower than the `foreach`.

Comment: @crush `ConvertAll` returns `List<T>`, no `IEnumerable<T>` and `AddRange` will use that to just copy underlying array of items, instead of iterating over the collection one item at the time.

Comment: On 10,000,000 iterations `ConvertAll` took 584,533 ticks. My `foreach` took 505,887. My original method with `Select` took 1,184,293 ticks.

Comment: @crush A tick is 100 nanoseconds. There's 1000000000 nanoseconds in a second. That's just over .1s for **ten million iterations**. This is not a performance worry, **at all.**

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Of course not. I'm just more interested in how it all works in the event that I'm doing a more intense operation =]. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I guess the real issue was that I was feeding an `IEnumerable` to `AddRange` instead of a `List<>` that it could just copy to the underlying array.

Comment: @crush Yes, if you consider .05 / 10,000,000 an issue.

Comment: @JefferyKhan Read my answer. Enumerable.Any is O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Because businessNames is a List, you can use List.ForEach:

```
businessNames.ForEach(bn => names.Add(bn.Name));
```

Comment: Strangely, this is slower than `ConvertAll<>`. Still faster than `Select<>`

Comment: @crush Based on MarcinJuraszek's answer, and looking at the remarks of List.Add vs List.AddRange, I see where you can save some performance by going with an AddRange(ConvertAll<>).  Another clarifying note: this isn't LINQ, List.ForEach has been around since .net 2.0, but Lambda Expressions make writing the delegate easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try making your `foreach` solution a bit quicker by expanding `List<string>` capacity manually before the loop:

```
var newList = new List<string>(names.Count + businessNames.Count);
newList.AddRange(names); // will perform `Array.Copy` on underlying array //

foreach (BusinessName name in businessNames) {
    newList.Add(name.Name);
}

names = newList; // replace old list with a new one //
```

When you call `Add` there is a check performed, to make sure that underlying array is big enough to contain one more element. If it's not, it is expanded by creating new one, copying all values and replacing it. When you add a lot of items it may happen multiple times. It may be quicker to just help and set initial `List<string>` capacity to required number of items.

Comment: True. I wonder can this be combined into a lambda statement + LINQ?

Comment: LINQ uses `foreach`-like loops inside anyway, so adding delegate (lambda) calls cost it won't be quicker then your custom `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BusinessName {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
void Main()
{
    List<BusinessName> businessNames = new List<BusinessName>();
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    names=names.Concat(businessNames.Select(b=>b.Name)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Of course, it would likely be faster if instead of using List<string> you used IEnumerable<string> since you don't have to convert from one to the other.

Comment: Why `Concat` over `AddRange` then?

Comment: Depends on what you are going to be doing with the names once you are done.  For example, if you have 128 names in businessNames, then executing the following `List<string>names=new List<string>(); names.AddRange(businessNames.Select(b=>b.Name)); var y=names.Take(10).ToList();` 10,000,000 times takes 0:54.232 seconds while `List<string>names=new List<string>(); var z=names.Concat(businessNames.Select(b=>b.Name)); var y=z.Take(10).ToList();` takes 0:02.123 seconds.  By keeping the query an IQueryable until you need it, especially if you are going to filter, or page it has to do less work.

Comment: IQueryables don't have to run through the enumeration until they are needed, so the concatenation is really just a virtual concatenation that doesn't happen until needed.  In the case of Take(10), only 10 items were ever iterated over where by doing an AddRange, the entire businessNames collection was iterated over and stored in names.

Comment: If this was LINQ over SQL or LINQ over EF, it would make even a bigger difference as the database would only return 10 items, where AddRange would return the entire businessNames to you and then you would filter it out on the application/webserver side.  Very bad for performance.

Comment: That said, however AddRange is faster if you are just doing LINQ over Objects, and you are always going to iterate over the entire result in the end.  And actually AddRange and ConvertAll aren't LINQ, but just functions of IEnumerable.

Comment: Thanks for adding the additional insight on use cases, lately I've seen several improperly used IEnumerable that end up being  performance killers; It can be easy to forget about the times where it's a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> names = (from b in buisnessNames select b.Name).ToList();
```

Or something like that...